# Form submission without reloading page

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a usercontrol containing a few textboxes and a submit button which runs inside a larger page, I have a few panels in the usercontrol so that when the user clicks submit the panels I toggle the visibility of the form panel with a panel saying "you have submitted".  The problem I am having is that when the form is submitted it refreshes the whole page.  I am wondering if there is any quick modification I can make to the usercontrol to have it only refresh itself without rewiring the form in ajax?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection();

    //Verify if entry exists
    if (CheckValid())
    {
        //Register data
        pnlSuccess.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        pnlDejaRepondu.Visible = true;
    }

    pnlForm.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there would be any easy modification as user control will be part of the page...you can either use asp.net ajax or jquery ajax call to stop reloading.

Comment: Just enclose content of user control into an UpdatePanel - it will cause partial postback of the usercontrol only

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Thanks! can you post your comment as the answer and I'll mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enclose content of the user control into an UpdatePanel.

UpdatePanel will cause partial postback of the user control content only, leaving the rest of the page intact.